# How do I get my inner class to implement an interface?

Tags: java

The question I need to do is "Add an inner class to the Calculatorclass, called SubtractCalculation. The inner class should implement TwoParameterCalculation" TwoParameterCalculation is an interface I had to create earlier.

My code looks like this [image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVjOn.png)

Comment: This is not a question, Stackoverflow members do not do your exercise for you.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Comment: The Google search term you're looking for is: "Java implement interface example".  Side note: Image editing programs make *terrible* IDEs.

Comment: Have you tried implements keyword  already ? It seems to compile..

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it. I didn't use your class names on purpose, so you can try to understand the code and not just copy/paste it.

```
public class OuterClass {

    public class InnerClass implements SomeInterface{

        @Override
        public void someMethod() {

        }
    }
}
```